Prepoblar una Base de datos Room en Android Studio desde .txt
tengo una pregunta por si me podéis echar una mano. Tengo algo de experiencia en programación pero hace muchos años que no programo y me he puesto ahora...
Estoy intentando hacer una base de datos local y quiero poblarla a través de un  archivo .txt que hay en mi carpeta raw.
Para ello he creado una Database:
@Database(entities=[ServiciosEntity::class],version=1, exportSchema = true)

abstract class ServiciosDatabase:RoomDatabase(){
    abstract fun serviciosDao():ServiciosDao

    companion object{
        fun getDatabase(ctx:Context):ServiciosDatabase{
            val db= Room.databaseBuilder(ctx,ServiciosDatabase::class.java,"nombredemidb").build()
            return db

        }
    }

}

He creado la Entity
Un DAO para consultas, etc...
Necesito que cuando el usuario entre en la actividad esa base de datos se cargue leyendo los datos de un .txt alojado en la carpeta raw.
He conseguido leer el texto y separar los campos, todo eso bien. El problema es que el método insert() de la Dao me pide como parámetros Strings.
Lo he intentado hacer de esta manera:
   GlobalScope().launch {
        if (base.serviciosDao().comprobarVacia() == 0) {
            val texto = leerArchivo()
            for (i in texto.indices) {
                val linea = texto[i].split(";".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
                base.serviciosDao().insert(ServiciosEntitie(Servicio = linea[0], Numerodetren = linea[1], Origen = linea[2], Destino=linea[3], Horasalida = linea[4], Horallegada = linea[5], Descanso = linea[6], Cartel = linea[7], Observaciones = linea[8]))

            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Servicios cargados: " + texto.size, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bienvenido a Servicios", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

linea[0] por ejemplo contiene un String = "54F"
Sin embargo no me lo acepta como válido en el argumento.
No obstante, si yo lo pongo manualmente:
if (base.serviciosDao().comprobarVacia() == 0) {
                base.serviciosDao().insert(
                    ServiciosEntitie(
                        Servicio = "1",
                        Numerodetren = "9002",
                        Origen = "AE",
                        Destino = "RI",
                        Horasalida = "11:05",
                        Horallegada = "11:45",
                        Descanso = "10",
                        Cartel = "AB",
                        Observaciones = "Destino AA"
                    )
                )

Entonces ahí sí que los acepta y los añade a la tabla.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?

¿Por qué no conviertes ese archivo .txt en una base de datos Sqlite directamente y prepropagas dicha base de datos. Realmente, la base de datos Sqlite no es otra cosa que un archivo, pero es al mismo tiempo una base de datos que Room puede leer como tal. Usar un .txt implica tener que programar código para leer ese archivo, hacer los CREATE TABLE, los INSERT, etc y además controlar que no vuelva a repetir eso cada vez que se inicia la aplicación, sino sólo la primera vez. Revisa la doc para más detalles.
